# Is it impossible to do PCA on the data whose # of variables are bigger than that of individuals?

Tags: r, pca

I am a new user of R and I try to do PCA on my data set using R. The dimension of data is 20x10000, i.e. # of features is 10000 and # of individuals is 20. It seems that prcomp() cannot handle the data exactly, because the dimension of calculated eigenvectors and new data is 20x20 and 10000x20 instead of 10000x10000 and 20x10000. I tried FactoMineR library also, but the results looked like that it looses some dimension, too. Is there any way to doing PCA on the data like this? :(

Comment: `prcomp` can handle datasets with more features than observations, I've done it myself several times. Can you add a dummy example of your failing code to help us locate the problem? Could it maybe be caused by missing values?

Comment: Is this a programming or a statistical question? If latter, I suggest this be moved to crossvalidated.com.

Comment: @Backlin   Actually, what I want to do is reducing data set's dimension, removing the features which has less priority. To do that, I just tried 'prcomp(X)' without any options where dim(X)=20x10000. I could just find that dim(prcomp(X)$rot)=10000x20 and dim(prcomp(X)$x)=20x20. Isn't it right that dim(prcomp(X)$rot)=10000x10000 and dim(prcomp(X)$x)=20x10000??? I tried to find eigenvectors manually also, but there are many NaN's in the output..

Comment: It sounds like `prcomp` is working fine. Since there are 20 observations in `x` (rows), the PCA projection will have a dimension of 20. `prcomp()$x` is the coordinates of `x` in the new space (20 observations as rows, with coordinates on 20 new basis vectors a.k.a. *components* as columns). `prcomp()$rot` holds the definition of the new basis vectors/components (columns) expressed in the coordinates of the original space (rows).

Comment: @Backlin  I should have thought prcomp() from the view of SVD. I just tried to find the the eigenvectors of covariance matrix which has dimension 10000x10000.. Things are more clearer due to your explanation. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

By reading the manual, it looks like no components are omitted by default but check the `tol` argument. The problem is with negative eigenvalues that may bet there (and often are) when you have less cases than individuals. (I think with 10000 cases and 20 individuals you will always have many negative eigenvalues.) See a simplified version of PCA I'm sometimes using that computes "PC loadings" the way they're usually used in psychology.

```
PCA <- function(X, cut=NULL, USE="complete.obs") {
   if(is.null(cut)) cut<- ncol(X)
   E<-eigen(cor(X,use=USE))
   vec<-E$vectors
   val<-E$values
   P<-sweep(vec,2,sqrt(val),"*")[,1:cut]
   P
   }
```

The "loadings" are, basically, eigenvectors multiplied by the square root of eigenvalues -- but there's a problem here if you have negative eigenvalues. Something similar may happen with prcomp.

If you just want to reconstruct your data matrix exactly (for whatever reason), you can easily use `svd` or `eigen` directly. /My example used correlation matrix but the logic is not confined to this case./

Comment: As you said, your function PCA produced NaN's with my data set. I tried to find eigenvectors with  `eigen` and there are many NaN's among the output.. Anyway, thank you for your advice.